# Is it possible to create an async JsonConverter for Json.Net?

Tags: c#, async-await, json.net

We have a scenario where we need to get schema metadata in order (de)serialize objects.  The schema repository only offers async calls.  How can I write a JsonConverter that is asynchronous?  If it's not possible, what alternatives are people using to handle async serialization in an ASP.NET pipeline?

I don't need async loading or saving of the json.  This is async fetching of metadata during the parsing and creation of the json. This allows the deserializer determine concrete and dynamic types and versions to load when parsing the data.

```cs
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var metadata = await metadataRepo.GetMetadata(value);
    /* inject custom json formatting from object */
}

public override override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jobject = JObject.Load(reader);
    var schema = jobject["schema"];
    var metadata = await metadataRepo.GetMetadata(schema);
    /* parse complex json formatting from object */
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Ooh, it seems like Json.NET *version 10* added back official async support: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2017/03/21/json-net-10-0-release-1-async-performance-documentation-and-more

Comment: `JsonTextReader` provides async reading as of 10.0.1, see http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2017/03/21/json-net-10-0-release-1-async-performance-documentation-and-more and https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.Async.cs.  However, the *serializer* does not, so it's hard to see how it would work with a `JsonConverter`.  Can you give a concrete example of what you want?

Comment: You can also load a `JToken` asynchronously with [`JToken.LoadAsync()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_LoadAsync.htm).

Comment: thank you for your help.  i added a code example to make it more clear what i'm looking for